# Converting list box Items to a String C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a WPF application. How to Convert ListBox items to single string Value?

I have 1 Text Box, an ADD Button to add items to a List Box, and a SAVE Button to SAVE items in Console Window.

How can I do this?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Im new to C#, So i dont have any idea to do this.

Comment: Ok , I have posted possible ans if that could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Concatenation of all items of list box

```
string allItems = string.Join(", ",listBox1.Items.OfType<object>());
```

//Concatenation of selected tiems of list box

```
string selectedItems= string.Join(", ",listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<object>());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listboxitems = listbox1.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>().Select(p => p.Content as string);
string result= String.Join("|", listboxitems .ToArray());
```

This will place
value1|value2|value3

Answer (score 0):

On which ever Button Click you want to Convert that Items to single String value Add this piece of code :

```
 Stringbuilder sb =new StringBuilder();



 private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Suppose that ListBox name is listBox1

        for(int i=0;listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {  
           sb.Append(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

use this Stringbuilder sb.ToString() to Your Text box

```
txtname.text =sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
  for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
  { 
    listBox1.Items.Add("Item " + x.ToString());
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
  {
    sb.Append(item.ToString());
  }
  Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try:

```
string[] listAsArray = listBoxPart.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new string content from your `TextBox`:

Assume that you have a `TextBox` name `textBox`,
You can get `string` content of the `textBox` by `Text` property.

You have to create 2 `Button` (s).

> Button ADD: To add the `string` from your `TextBox` to your `ListBox`
>
> Button SAVE: To save the `ListBox` items to a Console Window
>   See the code:

```
ListBoxItem item1 = new ListBoxItem();
item1.Content = textBox.Text;

listBox.Items.Add(item1);

// Do the same with item2, item 3,... item n
```

Show in a Console Window:

```
foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```